# React Redux-Thunk with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

So I am trying to type my Redux Actions with Redux Thunk

Here is an Action

```js
export function logout() {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    try {
      const value = localStorage.removeItem("token");

      dispatch(cons.updateLoginStatus(false));

      return true;

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the connect file

```js
const mapStateToProps = (store: IAppState) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: store.employee.isLoggedIn
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  logout
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Auth);
```

When I call `await this.props.logout();` I would like to access the returned `true` But typescript only sees the function being returned.

So how do I type the function to `await` for returned value?

Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can't get an event value from a dispatch: That defeats the purpose of the framework. You need to dispatch actions as a result of the login: `dispatch(LOGIN_FAILURE)`, etc... Take a look into redux-thunk or redux-saga for side effects like these.

Comment: Have you setup the thunk middleware ? https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#installation

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting seems a bit, anti-pattern. 
The function is meant to be fire and forget, so that you don't hang the UI.
The login function should dispatch to your reducer that state has now gone from

```
loggedIn: false
```

to

```
loggedIn: true
```

If you need some magic with response aka throw an exception if login fails, then I would recommend something like

```
this.props.login().catch(err => console.log(err)).then(() => doSomething));
```

However, I strongly recommend you just dispatch and listen to ComponentDidUpdate lifecycle hook to redirect or whatever you may need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the logout function by dispatching the appropriate action